# Should I use marshal if I am getting comma errors in JSON (Python)?

Tags: python, json, sockets, marshalling, pickle

I am actually using Python itself to dump a huge data structure (multiple lists and dictionaries) and am sending it over a socket to a client.

I keep getting a `ValueError: 'Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 16177 (char 16176)` at various different locations every time I run the program (it could be column 25000, or column 13000, it keeps changing).

Should I use marshal instead of json (or even pickle)? What is the most reliable format for large file sizes?

Comment: I also sometimes get the same error but with ':' instead

Comment: Does that happen when serializing or deserializing?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) (or cPickle if you're on Python 2.X) as it can serialize almost anything, including user-defined classes. And, as the docs say

> The `marshal` serialization format is not guaranteed to be portable across Python versions. Because its primary job in life is to support `.pyc` files, the Python implementers reserve the right to change the serialization format in non-backwards compatible ways should the need arise. The `pickle` serialization format is *guaranteed to be backwards compatible across Python releases*.

(Emphasis mine).

Another advantage of `pickle`:

> The `pickle` module keeps track of the objects it has already serialized, so that *later references to the same object won’t be serialized again. `marshal` doesn’t do this*.
>
> > This has implications both for recursive objects and object sharing.
> >     Recursive objects are objects that contain references to themselves.
> >     These are not handled by marshal, and in fact, attempting to marshal
> >     recursive objects will crash your Python interpreter. Object sharing
> >     happens when there are multiple references to the same object in
> >     different places in the object hierarchy being serialized. `pickle`
> >     stores such objects only once, and ensures that all other references
> >     point to the master copy. Shared objects remain shared, which can be
> >     very important for mutable objects.

You can also use [`dill`](http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/pathos/wiki/dill) if `pickle` fails to serialize some data.

Comment: So how would I go about integrated this into my current structure? I currently have a loop that gets data from a socket, and I decode as 'utf-8', add it to a list, and at the end, I json.loads(''.join(alldata)).

Now, I'll be adding bytes objects to the array instead of a string, so how do I condense that and then pickle.loads()?

Comment: @asuna, just follow the link in my answer! There you'll find some docs on `pickle`.

Comment: I wasn't able to understand how to join a bytes array, do you know if I can just ''.join() and the pickle.loads()?

Comment: @asuna, it seems you're using Python 3.X and unfortunately I've just started studying the difference between it and earlier versions, so, you should first check if the following works and only then use it in your code. As far as I understand, `bytes` is almost the same as `string`, but they're _not totally equal_. `bytes` should support almost all functions that `string` supports. So, you should be able to do `"".join(...)`. If you're reading from a file (or socket), you shouldn't need any `bytes`. You could do `a=pickle.loads(file.read())`.